# How to sort NSMutableArray in ascending order, iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have SQLite Database(DB) and made this to model class and taken the data of DB in NSMutableArray. My DB is similar to this DB.
**StudentName | RegisterNumber | DatesOfJoin(DoJ)**
I am displaying the DoJ in tableView successfully, but I wanna sort the DatesOfJoin in Ascending order and Descending order in tableView.
Any help would be appreciated and Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `NSSortDescriptor` and `sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors` to sort a mutable array.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"DatesOfJoin" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

Comment: This should be "sortedArrayUsingDescriptors"

Comment: Not if array is a mutable array.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the official documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

You got a lot of methods to sort the array:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context

- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator

- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr

- (NSArray *)sortedArrayWithOptions:(NSSortOptions)opts usingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

Answer (score 3):

For Desending Order:

```
NSArray *sorted = [Arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) return NSOrderedDescending;
    else return NSOrderedAscending;
}];
```

For Asending Order:

```
NSArray *sorted = [Arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    if ([obj1 intValue] < [obj2 intValue]) return NSOrderedAscending;
    else return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using :

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Over here your key" ascending:YES]; //Just write the key for which you want to have sorting & whole array would be sorted.
[self.messageAry sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
[descriptor release];
```

Hope that works,

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *res =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    //Sorting an array
    NSMutableArray *sortArray = [res valueForKey:@"Year"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    yearArray = [sortArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

In **Swift 3.0** Version

```
let sortedCapitalArray = yourArray.sorted {($0 as AnyObject).localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(($1 as AnyObject)as! String) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending}
```