# Conditionally retrieve fields from a dictionary, based on value of other field

Tags: ios, nsarray, compare, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterar over array of entity and get value of some key based on value of “other key” matche](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975702/iterar-over-array-of-entity-and-get-value-of-some-key-based-on-value-of-other-k)

Please, can anyone give me a hint or tip on how I can get the value of all the `salary` fields in my dictionary, if the status field is not null? I only want to retrieve the `salary` field from those objects in the dictionary where `status != null`. Note that my dictionary is dynamic, meaning I may have mor than four entries. Any help or hints highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
myArray=(
        {
        Name = "john1";
        Address = "san diego";
        Status = "active";
        salary = "100;

    },
        {
        Name = "steve ";
        Address = "birmingham";
        Status = "<null>";
        salary = "100;
    },
        {
         Name = "allan";
        Address = "san diego";
        Status = "active";
        salary = "100;
    },

     {
         Name = "peter";
        Address = "san diego";
        Status = "<null>";
        salary = "100;
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fast enumeration...

```
NSMutableArray* retreivedSalaries;

for (NSDictionary* dict in myArray) {
    if (![[dict objectForKey:@"Status"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
        [retreivedSalaries addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"salary"]];
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested so you may need to change this

```
for (int i=0;i< [myArray count];i++)
{
    if ([[[myArray objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @"Status"] isEqualToString: @"active"]) {

       NSLog(@"Salary is %@",[myArray objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @"salary"] )
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Status is not active");
    }
}
```

or you can use something like this

```
  for (NSDictionary *salary in myArray)
    {
        if([message valueForKey:@"Status"] isEqualToString: @"active")
           NSLog(@"Salary is %@",[message valueForKey:@"salary"]);      

    }
```

**Sorting salary**

*You can sort the keys and then create an NSMutableArray by iterating over them.*
[answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583020/can-i-sort-the-nsdictionary-on-basis-of-key-in-objective-c)

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[myArray allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys)
    [sortedValues addObject: [myArray objectForKey: key]];
```

Comment: the last one concept works! :D i just need to declare a NSString variable first and that variable will be the test inside the condition. thank you! (y)

Comment: is there a to sort the value of the salary?

Comment: sure you need to sort and add the value to a new nsmutable array, I have edited my answer look at it, and accept the answer if it had helped you

Comment: Space Dust. thank you for your time and effort but what is allKeys?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  NSDictionary *salaries = nil;
  NSArray *myArray .... ;


for (NSString * salary in salaries) {

    if ([myArray containsObject:@"salary"]) {

        if ([salaries objectForKey:@"salary"] != NULL) {

            NSLog (@"do something with salary: %@", salary);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i will try all your suggestion and give you a feedback. thank you all for your time

Comment: No problem. If anything goes wrong just let me know and I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: i will place the value of salary to nsmutable array can i sort it like ascending?

Comment: Yes, you can, just refer to these answers:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441856/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-in-ascending-order-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is iOS, myArray is an NSArray, and each dinamically person info is a NSDictionary, if this is the point, you can do the following:

```
for (NSDictionary *info in myArray) {

    if ([info objectForKey:@"Status"] != nil && ![[info objectForKey:@"Status"] isEqual:@"<null>") {
        // Store salary whatever you need and in the formar you need
        NSString *salary = [info objectForKey:@"salary"]; 
    }

}
```

I wrote the code without a compiler, so maybe there is some compilators errors (sorry). If I understand well your question, with that you can get the salary when the Status is not null.

Hope Helps!