# NSSortDescriptor Not Sorting Array

Tags: ios, nssortdescriptor

I am using `NSSortDescriptor` to sort my array on the basis of a key. Yesterday the same code was working very fine. But today its not sorting my array. I dont know what happened. There is not even a single code change.

Here is my code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:keyName ascending:is_asc];
NSArray *temp = [arrayDFRValues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
arrayDFRValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:temp];
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

Please anyone can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441856/how-to-sort-nsmutablearray-in-ascending-order-iphone

Comment: This is the same code that i am using. Unfortunately its all very fine. but still not sorting.

Comment: Show your array objects

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"keyName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDesc = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
[arrayDFRValues sortUsingDescriptors:sortDesc];
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Comment: keyName is an NSString Parameter

Comment: How is this different from the code snippet in the question?